# Is there a way to find out how many instances of the root user is logged into a linux machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, users

We have a handful of users that login to our Linux VM machine as root either through the vSphere client or through SSH and I want to see if there is a way to tell if multiple root users are logged in at the same time.

Comment: Actually having root directly connect from remote is your first problem.  For finding out whether and/or how many are logged in try **w** or **last|grep still** .

Comment: Run this command: `who`

Comment: Ugly, but   `who | cut -d '/' -f2 | wc -l`   (Filters on Pts/#, to avoid double counting people who logged in several times)

Comment: "w" "who" and "users" all show if there are duplicate root users. I tested it with a coworker.